# 50 Ω NMR circuit with 2 pF capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, impedance, capacitance, impedance-matching, high-frequency

**Context:**
Some pulses are being sent by a RF pulse generator to this circuit through a 50 Ω RF cable. The global impedance of the circuit must be equal to 50 Ω.

The "tuning" capacitor is a variable capacitor which is used to match the impedance of the coil at the resonance frequency which is 22.41 MHz.

The "matching" capacitor is a variable capacitor used to adjust the global impedance of the NMR circuit to obtain the needed 50 Ω global impedance. It is important to have the same impedance for the RF cable and our circuit.

[image: NMR Circuit]

**Problem:**
The capacitors which are used are the SGNMNC1206. These are capacitors designed for NMR and frequencies around 25 MHz. As you can see on the datasheet, their capacitance goes from 2 pF to 20 pF. **How can you have a 50 Ω NMR circuit (LC parallel, in series with C) when the minimum impedance of these capacitors (at 22.41 MHz, for their maximal value: 20 pF) is 318 Ω ?**

[image: Capacitors datasheet]

I must be missing something because, as I said, these capacitors are designed for such circuits and frequencies.

Comment: Improper to compare a 318 *reactance* to 50 ohm *resistance*. The resistive part of that 318 *reactance* is *at least* 1500 times smaller (0.2 ohms). To be fair, two other reactances are in that resonant circuit, each having its own quality factor (Q). Until all three Q's are known, the optimum value of capacitance for \$C_{match}\$ can't be calculated.

Comment: NMR is presumably [nuclear magnetic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance) (and not, e.g., normalised modal reactance).

Answer (score 6):

There's one important component you've not shown, and that's the loss resistance of the L, plus any losses in the medium it's coupled to.

If you wonder how the matching C can go below 50 Ω impedance, notice that it's in series with an LC circuit, which is presumably tuned below resonance so it looks inductive rather than capacitive. An L and C have impedances of opposite signs, so their magnitudes subtract. If their impedance magnitudes are equal, then their combined impedance is zero! Or more correctly, just the resistive losses.

Taking the circuit as a whole, the two Cs and the L act as an impedance transformer, transforming the loss resistance of the coil up to 50 Ω to present to the generator.

Presumably the user manual for this equipment gives a method for adjusting both capacitors to achieve the match. It's not as simple as tuning the tuning C for resonance, but there will be procedure that converges quickly.

Comment: The LC parallel circuit is tuned precisely at the resonance frequency of 22.41 MHz, nor above or bellow. And I'm quite sure that what you said is true but for LC series circuit. In fact, at the resonnance frequency, the impedance of the LC parallel circuit is at its maximum and seen as purely resistiv

Comment: @SimonRondeau How is it tuned to resonance? Is it decoupled from the matching C, or is that still in circuit?

Comment: The pure value of L doesn't change however when you insert a sample in the probe it affects the homogeneity of the magnetic field and the radio frequency circuit that delivers the pulses and detects the signals. Why? Because it basically changes the value of L. You then adjust the value of C (the Cs are variable capacitors) so that the impedance of C matches the new impedance of L and so the resonance frequency of the LC parallel circuit matches the frequency produced by the spectrometer's amplifiers. In practice this is like tuning a radio to the frequency of a particular station.

Answer (score 3):

Designed to NMR-circuit at certain frequency means there's no materials which generate own resonances near the operating frequency which would spoil the measurement. In addition the manufacturer promises certain minimum Q.

The matching to 50 ohms means 2 things simultaneously

- the reactance of the circuit is zero
- the resistive part of the impedance is 50 ohms

These are the function of the whole circuit. RF circuit designers have developed numerous impedance transforming circuits which do the trick. The resistive losses of the probe coil (=coil resistance and the absorbtion in the material sample) and other parts really get transformed to resistive 50 ohms when seen through a well designed LC circuit which is properly tuned, too.

No single capacitor defines alone what the circuit does, so thinking "I cannot see how a capacitive reactance more than 300 ohms could make 50 ohms" is perfectly right: The capacitor doesn't make it alone, it's the result of interactions between the inductive and capacitive parts. The total functional design needs tricky calculations with complex phasor equations. It's also theoretically possible to find a good combination with a circuit analyzing program, but its much better to use an already known circuit and its design formulas.

Read this. It's about NMR probe design exercises. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/cmr.a.21221

**ADD:** a simple example of impedance transformation with a LC circuit:

[image]

The resonator L1C1 has parallel resonance at about 43.5 MHz. It's not tuned at 25 MHz. Resistor R1 presents (guessed) losses caused by a material sample inside L1 at 25 MHz. My intuition says that the losses occur as increased conduction, the total impedance of L1, C1, R1 - circuit between node 2 and GND has a reduced value, ideally with no losses it would be infinite at 43.5 MHz.

The next image presents the complex impedance of L1, C1, R1. Red curve is the imaginary part in ohms and the blue curve is the real part in ohms.

[image]

At 25 MHz the impedance (in ohms) is about 50 + 151j where j is the imaginary unit. The impedance is inductive when the frequency is lower than the resonant frequency 43.5 MHz.

But the inductive reactance can be compensated by adding a capacitor which has capacitive reactance = 151 ohms at 25 MHz. That's about 42 pF, so the next circuit C2, L1, C1, R1 would be matched to the 50 ohm source at 25 MHz:

[image]

The component values are rounded to easy numbers and the loss resistance R1 has no basement on real NMR measurements. In addition there's no losses given to the inductor nor capacitors, so consider this only as an example of impedance transformation without a transformer.

BTW. I do not have NMR measurement equipment, but I have worked with RF tuning circuits.

Comment: Thanks, the publication seems awesome.

Comment: "Parallel tuned circuits generally have impe-dances at resonance that are much greater than 50Ω. This must be followed by or combined with some trans-former-like device to transform the too-large parallel imped-ance to 50Ω." 
Found that in the article. So apparently the impedance which is too high is just somehow transformed

Comment: UPDATE : after seeing the very interesting addings that you made in your answer, I was wondering what software did you use ? And why the resistance R1 which represents the losses of L1 is in parallel and not in series with L1 ?

Comment: It's Micro-Cap 10. It has been freeware few years because the developer retired and made his earlier high cost product available for free. There's also later free versions, but v10 seems to work well. A lossy sample inside L1 generates apparent parallel resistance and it can also reduce the inductance. Wire resistance is modeled easiest as series resistor. Total loss can as well be modeled as series as parallel resistor, but the effective inductance depends on frequency - it's not an ideal inductor. For that reason tuning is needed.

Comment: In addition, in your representation we can see that at the resonance frequency which is 43.5 MHz, the imaginary part is equal to 0 and the real part is at its maximum. That is the point I don't understand : why does the resistiv part (the real part) increase ?

Comment: The 500 ohms real part at the resonant frequency is R1. In resonance the currents of L1 and C1 cancel each other (=opposite phases), there's only R1 loading the source at the resonant frequency. As said I assumed the inductor losses are mostly caused by the material sample inside L1 and they are modeled as R1. That assumption can be too simple in real NMR measurement systems.

Comment: Yeah no worries I appreciate the time you spend to to enlighten me. Send when you can :D

Comment: @SimonRondeau get it from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/lq4agx9ehz60v4r/LC_tuner0.CIR?dl=0 BTW it's not wise to distribute one's email address with no control. Minimize the damage by removing your message.

Comment: Thanks ! I appreciate all of what you do for me !

Comment: But now the circuit is tuned for 43.5 MHz and matched for 25 MHz. Therefore, in my case in which I want to use a frequency of 22.41 MHz, you mean that the circuit is tuned at a much higher frequency ?

Comment: The parallel resonant circuit L1, C1 has alone resonance frequency 43,5 MHz. But that's not the whole circuit, there's also R1 and C2. The whole circuit has resonance at about 25 MHz., one where the total impedance seen by the 50 ohms source is resistive 50 ohms and there's zero reflection back to the source.  See this as a trick which converts 500 ohms to 50 ohms at 25 MHz. The change of the resonant frequency because the inserted coupling capacitor becomes a part of the resonant system is discussed in page 5 in the linked document.

Answer (score 1):

Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm). See also newsletters on the website for informations.

[link1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4fs7mxyzibb2o9/NMR%20nuclear%20detection%20v0000.cir?dl=0), [link2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9nii30rhasfl8t/NMR%20nuclear%20detection%20v010.cir?dl=0), [link3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9sdzjgkuf1gs50/NMR%20nuclear%20detection%20v020.cir?dl=0)

Here is what I have used in some configurations (theoretical point of view).
EE&O
If the frequency is nearest the same value, something like this can be used.
Amplitude generator = 50 V peak.
Peak voltage at output = 1250 V peak. (line isolation must be higher ...).
Inductor current = 3 A peak. ( with generator, R4 adjusts the value of inductor current).

[image]

AC Analysis with parameter C2.

[image]

However, here is what can be seen in a classical circuit (22.5 MHz).

AC Analysis :

[image]

TRAN Analysis :

[image]

Disconnected S3 (NB: line is now a lossy line).

[image]

Comment: what software did you use ?

Comment: ALL FREE microcap v12 http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip

Comment: The resistor R4 represents the impedance of the transmission unit that the circuit has to match ?

Comment: R4 can be the internal impedance of the generator (+ added limiting resistor eventually) which limits the output current/voltage (perfect generator voltage ) at the input of the "system". It does not "really" match the circuit in the sense of a "transmission line".

Comment: The "line" used in the first picture is used as a "line transformer" (lambda /4). Must "withstand" the high voltage (x2?).

Comment: Added links in answer. Take care of the switches ... for AC or TRAN Analysis, If you don't see what is in my pictures. Use the interactive capabilities with point/click components, and then up/down arrow keys (not for switches).

Comment: I did the simulation thanks to the files you attached in your answer :D. However, I don't understand the utility of V3, S3, and the switch just before VE.

Comment: V3 is for wave modulated or not. S3 short output after the pulse has been sent - so the NMR "detector" inside is not influenced by "end of current pulse" which does not end at a zero crossing (it is why also there are variables tp and tpf to adjust the time, change the value of tpf with pointing label then use arrows up/down) see the effect by switching near label AC (so S3 has disconnected from VS). Switch before VE is used for AC analysis (directly wiring to sine generator "required").

Comment: See my last picture for disconnected S3.